Getting mean value from specific cells in large data frame
I have a large data set with 48 columns and 481 rows. I need to calculate the mean value of every column, in every 12th row. So cell [12,1], [24,1] etc., then again for column 2.
I haven't figured out a simple way of doing it for more than five rows at the time.
This is how I've done it previously, which isn't optimal, but I can't figure out a better way.
# getting the mean of every 96th row (5 rows), then plotting it, and repeat for every column
# modified_c... is the df
for (l in 1:47){
    A = (as.numeric(modified_Candida_albicans_5plates_48h[row,column]))
    row = row + 96
    B = (as.numeric(modified_Candida_albicans_5plates_48h[row,column]))
    row = row + 96
    C = (as.numeric(modified_Candida_albicans_5plates_48h[row,column]))
    row = row + 96
    D = (as.numeric(modified_Candida_albicans_5plates_48h[row,column]))
    row = row + 96
    E = (as.numeric(modified_Candida_albicans_5plates_48h[row,column]))
    meana = c(A,B,C,D,E)
    meanb = mean(meana)
    points(time,meanb,pch = 19, col="blue")
    time = time + 1
    column = column + 1
    row = row - 384
  }


If your data frame is called df, use
colMeans(df[seq(0, nrow(df), 12),])

Explanation:

df[seq(0, nrow(df), 12),] takes the subset consisting out of rows 12, 24, 36, ...
colMeans() calculates the mean of every column.


Here's tidyverse:
library(tidyverse) 

set.seed(42)

# Toy data provided by @Jay.sf
m <- 100 
n <- 10
my_df <- data.frame(replicate(n, sort(runif(m*1))))

# Row selection helper (must be numeric)     # From @Jan's solution:
my_rows <- 12 * 1:(trunc(nrow(my_df)/12))    # seq(0, nrow(df), 12)

# Slice the lines and summarise what you want
my_output <- my_df %>% 
  slice(my_rows) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), \(x) mean(x)))

The output:
> glimpse(my_output)
Rows: 1
Columns: 10
$ X1  <dbl> 0.5628128
$ X2  <dbl> 0.5505473
$ X3  <dbl> 0.4695385
$ X4  <dbl> 0.5436174
$ X5  <dbl> 0.4879784
$ X6  <dbl> 0.5123233
$ X7  <dbl> 0.5313123
$ X8  <dbl> 0.5462177
$ X9  <dbl> 0.5062638
$ X10 <dbl> 0.4951283

Created on 2024-05-19 with reprex v2.1.0

Maybe you're looking for
> df[seq_len(nrow(df)) %% 12 == 0, ] |> colMeans() 
       X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6        X7        X8        X9       X10 
0.5628128 0.5505473 0.4695385 0.5436174 0.4879784 0.5123233 0.5313123 0.5462177 0.5062638 0.4951283 

And, since apparently you want to plot it:
> df[seq_len(nrow(df)) %% 12 == 0, ] |> 
+   colMeans() |> 
+   matplot(pch=3, col=2, xaxt='n', xlab='Time', ylab='Mean', ylim=c(0, 1)) +
+   axis(1, at=seq_len(ncol(df)), labels=names(df))


or
> df[seq_len(nrow(df)) %% 12 == 0, ] |> 
+   colMeans() |> 
+   barplot(xlab='Time', ylab='Mean', col=2, border=2)



Data:
m <- 100; n <- 10
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  replicate(n, sort(runif(m*1)))
)

